# How to put PayPal Test Button on a site?

Tags: testing, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-buttons

I'm trying to follow [these instructions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/ht_test-pps-buttons/). I log in to developer.paypal.com, then to www.sandbox.paypal.com with a Business account from [developer.paypal.com's Sandbox Test Accounts page](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/). Go to Merchant Services, click "My saved buttons". Domain changes to www.paypal.com (is it as it should be?). I choose Buy Now button, specify item name and price, and click Create Button. Remove code protection, copy the code, paste it to a site. Open the page, click Buy Now button, which gets me to www.paypal.com, specify Personal account's credentials from [developer.paypal.com's Sandbox Test Accounts page](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/). Click Log In, but it says:

```
Please check your email address and password and try again

Please make sure you have entered your email address correctly.

Please re-enter your PayPal password.
```

And yep, I checked if I can log in with those credentials to www.sandbox.paypal.com. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, it's because I have account of a country where I can't accept payments. As such, I can't put even a test button on a site.

**UPD** I checked again, and it now works. I see two possibilities here: 1) temporary paypal glitch, 2) I created the button under personal account.

Answer (score 0):

This occurred most likely because you had another instance of a paypal.com page loaded as it should not have redirected you to paypal.com. I have seen this many times.

**Resolution**:

1. Clear browser cache and cookies where you are loading your sandbox.paypal.com account
2. If you want to load your live paypal account do it with a
   different browser as sandbox and paypal.com clash with live & sandbox instances loaded on the same browser; if you do not have your live paypal account loaded, but did prior to a sandbox login you can experience the same issue; follow same resolution steps noted here
3. login to sandbox.paypal.com with business email account you created from
   developer.paypal.com
4. Then view your saved buttons, view code and test